# RuntimeError due to inplace operation in GAN generator architecture with skip connections

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I get the following error for a GAN model I am using to perform image colorization. It uses the LAB color space as is common in image colorization. The generator generates the a ad b channels for a given L channel. The discriminator is fed all three channels after concatenation.

`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [64, 64, 128, 128]], which is output 0 of ReluBackward0, is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`

I believe the error is due to the skip connections but I cannot quite put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the model:

```
class NetGen(nn.Module):
    '''Generator'''
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetGen, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu1 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.relu2 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.relu3 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.relu4 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.relu5 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

        self.deconv6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        self.relu6 = nn.ReLU()

        self.deconv7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
        self.relu7 = nn.ReLU()

        self.deconv8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm8 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        self.relu8 = nn.ReLU()

        self.deconv9 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bnorm9 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu9 = nn.ReLU()

        self.deconv10 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 2, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1, bias=False)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        

    def forward(self, x):
        h = x
        h = self.conv1(h)
        h = self.bnorm1(h)
        h = self.relu1(h) 
        pool1 = h

        h = self.conv2(h)
        h = self.bnorm2(h)
        h = self.relu2(h) 
        pool2 = h

        h = self.conv3(h) 
        h = self.bnorm3(h)
        h = self.relu3(h)
        pool3 = h

        h = self.conv4(h) 
        h = self.bnorm4(h)
        h = self.relu4(h)
        pool4 = h

        h = self.conv5(h) 
        h = self.bnorm5(h)
        h = self.relu5(h)

        h = self.deconv6(h)
        h = self.bnorm6(h)
        h = self.relu6(h) 
        h += pool4

        h = self.deconv7(h)
        h = self.bnorm7(h)
        h = self.relu7(h) 
        h += pool3

        h = self.deconv8(h)
        h = self.bnorm8(h)
        h = self.relu8(h)
        h += pool2

        h = self.deconv9(h)
        h = self.bnorm9(h)
        h = self.relu9(h)
        h += pool1

        h = self.deconv10(h)
        h = self.tanh(h) 
        return h

class NetDis(nn.Module):
    '''Discriminator'''
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetDis, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),

            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),

            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),

            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),

            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),


            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 8, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),

            nn.Conv2d(512, 1, 1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.main(x)
```

Here is the weight init function:

```
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
```

Here is the training and validation code:

```
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, epochs, batch_size, learning_rate, num_workers):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.train_paths = train_paths
        self.val_paths = val_paths        
        self.real_label = 1
        self.fake_label = 0

    def train(self):             
        train_dataset = ColorizeData(paths=self.train_paths)
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers,pin_memory=True, drop_last = True)
        # Model
        model_G = NetGen().to(device)
        model_D = NetDis().to(device)

        model_G.apply(weights_init)
        model_D.apply(weights_init)

        optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(model_G.parameters(),
                             lr=self.learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999),
                             eps=1e-8, weight_decay=0)
        optimizer_D = torch.optim.Adam(model_D.parameters(),
                             lr=self.learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999),
                             eps=1e-8, weight_decay=0)
        
        criterion = nn.BCELoss()
        L1 = nn.L1Loss()

        model_G.train()
        model_D.train()


        # train loop
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            print("Starting Training Epoch " + str(epoch + 1))
            for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):                                                    
                inputs, input_ab, input_l = data
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                input_ab = input_ab.to(device)
                input_l = input_l.to(device)


                model_D.zero_grad()
                label = torch.full((self.batch_size,), self.real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, input_ab], dim=1))
                errD_real = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)
                errD_real.backward()

                fake = model_G(input_l)
                label.fill_(self.fake_label)

                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, fake.detach()], dim=1))
                errD_fake = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)
                errD_fake.backward()
                errD = errD_real + errD_fake
                optimizer_D.step()

                model_G.zero_grad()
                label.fill_(self.real_label)  
                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, fake], dim=1))
                errG = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)
                errG_L1 = L1(fake.view(fake.size(0),-1), input_ab.view(input_ab.size(0),-1))
                errG = errG + 100 * errG_L1
                errG.backward()
                optimizer_G.step()  


            print(f'Training: Epoch {epoch + 1} \t\t Discriminator Loss: {\
                errD / len(train_dataloader)}  \t\t Generator Loss: {\
                errG / len(train_dataloader)}')
            
            if (epoch + 1) % 1 == 0:
                errD_val, errG_val, val_len = self.validate(model_D, model_G, criterion, L1)
                print(f'Validation: Epoch {epoch + 1} \t\t Discriminator Loss: {\
                        errD_val / val_len}  \t\t Generator Loss: {\
                        errG_val / val_len}')
                
            torch.save(model_G.state_dict(), '../Results/Model_GAN/Generator/saved_model_' + str(epoch + 1) + '.pth')
            torch.save(model_D.state_dict(), '../Results/Model_GAN/Discriminator/saved_model_' + str(epoch + 1) + '.pth')


    def validate(self, model_D, model_G, criterion, L1):

        model_G.eval()
        model_D.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            valid_loss = 0.0
            val_dataset = ColorizeData(paths=self.val_paths)
            val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=self.num_workers, pin_memory=True, drop_last = True)
            for i, data in enumerate(val_dataloader):
                inputs, input_ab, input_l = data
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                input_ab = input_ab.to(device)
                input_l = input_l.to(device)

                label = torch.full((self.batch_size,), self.real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, input_ab], dim=1))
                errD_real = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)

                fake = model_G(input_l)
                label.fill_(self.fake_label)
                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, fake.detach()], dim=1))
                errD_fake = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)
                
                errD = errD_real + errD_fake

                label.fill_(self.real_label)  
                output = model_D(torch.cat([input_l, fake], dim=1))
                errG = criterion(torch.squeeze(output), label)
                errG_L1 = L1(fake.view(fake.size(0),-1), input_ab.view(input_ab.size(0),-1))
                errG = errG + 100 * errG_L1

        return errD, errG, len(val_dataloader)
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by @manaclan here is the code I use to run the pipeline:

```
trainer = Trainer(epochs = 100, batch_size = 64, learning_rate = 0.0002, num_workers = 2)
trainer.train()
```

Here is the data loader:

```
class ColorizeData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, paths):
        self.input_transform = T.Compose([T.ToTensor(),
                                          T.Resize(size=(256,256)),
                                          T.Grayscale(),
                                          T.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))
                                          ])
        self.lab_transform = T.Compose([T.ToTensor(),
                                          T.Resize(size=(256,256)),
                                          T.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                                          ])
        self.paths = paths

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.paths)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        image = Image.open(self.paths[index]).convert("RGB")
        input_image = self.input_transform(image)
        image_lab = rgb2lab(image)
        image_lab = self.lab_transform(image_lab)
        image_l = image_lab[0, :, :]
        image_ab = image_lab[1:3, :, :]
        return (input_image.float(), image_ab.float(), image_l.float().reshape(1, 256, 256))
```

Here are the imports:

```py
from typing import Tuple
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torch
import numpy as np
import os
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision
import torch.nn.functional as functional
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
from PIL import Image
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from skimage.color import lab2rgb, rgb2lab, rgb2gray
from skimage import io

from torchvision.transforms.functional import resize
```

To reproduce the error, just use any dataset of color images.
I have the following code to get my train, test, and validation images from the folder "Dataset":

```
path = "../Dataset/"
paths = np.array(glob.glob(path + "/*.jpg"))
rand_indices = np.random.permutation(len(paths))          # Number of images in dataset
train_indices, val_indices, test_indices = rand_indices[:3600], rand_indices[3600:4000], rand_indices[4000:]
train_paths = paths[train_indices]
val_paths = paths[val_indices]
test_paths = paths[test_indices]
```

**NOTE**: I am using Google Colab, maybe this might be a potential problem? Also, I am using torch version 1.10.0+cu111.
I did use a sequential model without skip connections for the generator before this, and I did not have this error then.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet that produce the error? Only model definition and trainer is hard to narrow down the problem

Comment: @manaclan I have edited my post. Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: In your train function of `Trainer` class, variable `errD ` is in difference scope with the `print(f'Training: .....)`  call hence causing `local variable 'errD' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Huh, that's strange, I don't have that error coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, the problem is the inplace skip connection written as `h += poolX.` Writing this update out of place as `h = h + poolX` fixed it. h is needed for gradient calculation in some layers, so inplace modification will mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use the output of the layers directly for the skip connections, like this:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    h = x
    h = self.conv1(h)
    h = self.bnorm1(h)
    h1 = self.relu1(h) 

    h = self.conv2(h1)
    h = self.bnorm2(h)
    h2 = self.relu2(h) 

    h = self.conv3(h2) 
    h = self.bnorm3(h)
    h3 = self.relu3(h)

    h = self.conv4(h3) 
    h = self.bnorm4(h)
    h4 = self.relu4(h)

    h = self.conv5(h4) 
    h = self.bnorm5(h)
    h = self.relu5(h)

    h = self.deconv6(h5)
    h = self.bnorm6(h)
    h = self.relu6(h) 
    h += h4

    h = self.deconv7(h)
    h = self.bnorm7(h)
    h = self.relu7(h) 
    h += h3

    h = self.deconv8(h)
    h = self.bnorm8(h)
    h = self.relu8(h)
    h += h2

    h = self.deconv9(h)
    h = self.bnorm9(h)
    h = self.relu9(h)
    h += h1

    h = self.deconv10(h)
    h = self.tanh(h) 
    return h
```

Comment: It gives the same error with these changes too (I did change the h5 to h because it gave an error that it was not defined).